# I don't know what I am doing wrong. Code for opening a pygame window

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, background, window

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *


DISPLAY_SURF = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
#Sets the resolution to 640 pixels by 720 pixels

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.FPS = 60
        self.fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
        pygame.display.set_caption("The Hunt")
        img = pygame.image.load("Graphics/background.png")
        self.surface.blit(img)
        #This class sets the basic attributes for the window.
        #The clock is set to 60 and the name of the window
        #is set to The Hunt which is a working title for my project


    def run(self):
        while True:
            pygame.display.update()
            self.fps_clock.tick(self.FPS)
            self.process_game()

            #This updates the window display to refresh every clock tick


    def process_game(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


game = Game()
#This creates an instance of the class Game which gives all the attributes
#  and behaviours to this instance
game.run()
#Calling this function generates a window with the attributes defined.
```

> I need some help. I have already checked if it is in the same folder, the file is definitely a png and I spelt all the folder names and the destination correctly. I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You put up some code and a question title. You haven't told us what you expect your code should be doing, and what you actually observe it doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question despite that it is not really a good one for Stack Overflow. On this site, you'll have to be more specific and detailed, because no one intends to read through a huge lot of code for you. I did however pickup some things that I think can be fixed  **( some of these are opinion based, something that your question should never force an answer to have)**, but... here it is anyway:

For starters, when you construct a class, you use parenthesis after the class name, even if it's not going to inherit anything form another class. So change the line where you construct the Game class to this:

```
class Game():
```

Second thing about this code is that if your going to create the pygame window surface inside the Game() class, I don't understand why you're creating another window at the beginning of your code. If there is a reason for this please explain it in a comment in your code.

The last thing is more opinion-based . I don't know how many people create Pygame GUI applications like this, but it would be simpler to not use classes so you could understand the code better. When I create a Pygame GUI, I define the window, then the sprites, then I run the main game loop in a While Loop. Here is how I would normally structure your program:

```
#import pygame
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#Initialize pygame and define colours
pygame.init()
white = 255,255,255

#Sets the resolution to 640 pixels by 720 pixels and caption for pygame window
DISPLAY_SURF = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Hunt!")

#Create a clock object
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

#Define a variable to refer to image
image = pygame.image.load("download.jpg")

#Start main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    DISPLAY_SURF.fill(white)
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I do use classes when creating a sprite, so I can create several instances of it, as well as keep functions I want to perform on the sprite all in one place. Doing this for the WHOLE program does work, and I suppose it's more "pythonic" (since python is object-oriented) but is still unnecessary for something like this. Here is a reference that [teaches pygame in a similar way to how I code it](https://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf), which I personally find to be an excellent tutorial.

Many people also put this code in a main() function and then run it, which is also a wildly used and accepted practice.